# Could someone tell me what is 奶思 means?

Tags: meaning

I found this pic on Weibo so I'd really want to know the meaning.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

It probably means the English word `nice`(pronunciation).

This pic is very similar to those Chinese Internet meme pics. For example you may have also seen one with the word `因吹丝挺`, which means `interesting`.

These meme pics are often ironic.

[image: 因吹丝挺]

Answer (score 3):

It's just Chinglish for "nice!"...

Comment: Chinglish is an interesting term... I read it in 通勝: "可士必吐 = Hospital. " when I was a kid.